# Web resource exploration via APIs in GCP, AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

When I worked with Azure I found this resource very handy: https://resources.azure.com. Sometimes you can retrieve compact resources information easily.

Also, you can call those APIs directly from Azure CLI:

```
az rest --method [get|post] --uri [] --query []`
```

Are there any similar tools available for AWS and GCP?

Comment: Google has a similar **Try this API**. Example: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/list

Comment: There is also **Google APIs Explorer**: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the Google resources,Retrieves a list of buckets for a given project, ordered in the list lexicographically by name. [Try it now.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/list#try-it)
The authenticated user must have [sufficient permission](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-json) to use this method.

Sample Http Request:
GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b

For More information find the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/list) .